# Node.JS, Sequelize: Package exports for 'C:\(my project folder)\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\uuid' do not define a valid '.' target

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm getting this error after installing [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/getting-started.html) library:

```
Error: Package exports for 'C:\(my project folder)\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\uuid' do not define a valid '.' target
at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:545:13)
at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:459:14)
at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:12)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:577:20)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:27)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\(my project folder)\node_modules\sequelize\lib\utils.js:7:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
```

I went to node_modules\uuid\index.js file and there's only one variable in module.exports:

```
var v1 = require('./v1');
var v4 = require('./v4');

var uuid = v4;
uuid.v1 = v1;
uuid.v4 = v4;

module.exports = uuid;
```

And also in node_modules\sequelize\lib\utils.js, where this error seems to be from, I can see such code (lines 7,8). But I don't know why it fails.

```
const uuidv1 = require('uuid').v1;
const uuidv4 = require('uuid').v4;
```

So, I'm pretty confused what can I do to fix this problem.
Node version is v14.6.0 (just upgraded from v13 in hope that would fix the problem)

Comment: which version ? anyway read the doc https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid

Comment: I didn't install uuid by myself, I guess that Sequelize did it

Comment: Also ran "npm install --save uuid" and node said 1 package was updated. Yet error persists. Honestly I would like not to modify code of these libraries, as I don't know what they do, I'd like to know how other people fixed this, maybe I installed something wrong

Comment: Temporary fix... go to sequelize's package.json and downgrade uuid from 8.1.0 to 3.4.0 then run npm update. I guess this is a bad fix.